# Biopython to highlight pathway based on a compound

Tags: biopython

I am new to biopython and the KGML module. I am wondering if there is a way to highlight a pathway based on a compound. Below is the code I am using, with the help of the KGML tutorial:

```
import Bio
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.KEGG.REST import *
from Bio.KEGG.KGML import KGML_parser
from Bio.Graphics.KGML_vis import KGMLCanvas
from Bio.Graphics.ColorSpiral import ColorSpiral
from IPython.display import Image, HTML
import random

# A bit of code that will help us display the PDF output
def PDF(filename):
    return HTML('<iframe src=%s width=700 height=350></iframe>' % filename)

# A bit of helper code to shorten long text
def head(text, lines=10):
    """ Print the first lines lines of the passed text.
    """
    print '\n'.join(text.split('\n')[:lines] + ['[...]'])

def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    rgb = tuple([int(255*val) for val in rgb])
    return '#' + ''.join([hex(val)[2:] for val in rgb]).upper()



sbi_map = KGML_parser.read((kegg_get("sbi01100", "kgml").read())) 

compArray = ["cpd:C00186","cpd:C00079"]
for element in sbi_map.compounds:
    print(element.name)
    if element.name in compArray:
        for graphic in element.graphics:
            print(graphic.type)
            graphic.bgcolor = rgb_to_hex((138,0,67))
            graphic.width = 25
```

However, this is only highlighting the compound element. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight a pathway"? You mean all reactions in the map or what exactly do you try to do?

Comment: @Cleb, yes I mean all the reactions on the map. For example, the compound is found with in the carbon fixation pathway, I would like to highlight it.

Comment: By pathways you mean modules? I think then you will first have to find all modules in which your compound occurs. And then highlight those; right now you only find metabolites not any corresponding reactions etc.

Comment: @Cleb, I am trying to get that information but am not sure how to do that.

Comment: The pathways you can get by doing `kegg_get("cpd:C00186").read()`. You will still have to parse this though. Then you get a list of pathways which you can try to map onto `sbi01100`.

Comment: @Cleb, thanks for this. I have found that path:map00402 is one of the pathways and used the code below but it is not highlighting that pathway.                                                                     `for element in sbi_map.maps:
 print(element.name)
 if element.name =="path:map00402":
  for graphic in element.graphics:
    print(graphic.type)
    graphic.bgcolor = rgb_to_hex((138,0,67))
    graphic.fgcolor = rgb_to_hex((138,0,67))
    graphic.width = 40`

Comment: I am not sure whether one can highlight `map` there or only modules (the selection on the left is only for modules).